# PyQgis question: How to change or set active layer?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

Developing a QGIS plugin, I found that if no layer is selected in the Layers panel I can iterate over all layers and do anything to them, but "activate" them.

Could someone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can set the active layer using the qgis.utils.iface object (i.e. [QgisInterface](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#ac42281407013002b56ff7ed422c77336)):

```
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(QgsMapLayer)  # returns bool
# or
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().setCurrentLayer(QgsMapLayer)  # returns bool
```

Clearing the selection, or the active layer (underlined QTreeWidget item in QGIS 2.0), in the legend is a bit more involved:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
lg = qgis.utils.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QTreeWidget, 'theMapLegend')
lg.selectionModel().clear()  # clear just selection
lg.setCurrentItem(None)  # clear selection and active layer
```

There are three ways to retrieve the current layers, relative to what you may want to do:

~ via [QList< QgsMapLayer * > QgsLegendInterface::layers()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendInterface.html#a23af9546e085ca6485b1b8e59c14c6db)

```
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().layers()  # returns [layer, ...]
```

~ via [QList< QgsMapLayer * > QgsMapCanvas::layers()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html#a43c643d06e315b90c25e10d8a4644f4e):

```
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layers()  # returns [layer, ...]
```

~ via [const QMap< QString, QgsMapLayer * > & QgsMapLayerRegistry::mapLayers()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerRegistry.html#acde21d86d0c65930f54d9b709021e31e):

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()  # returns {'layer_id': layer, ...}
```

[Reference these answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26257) for information about the differences in those layer collections.