# Iterating clip over multiple layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip, iteration

I have multiple vector layers and a fishnet grid. I would like to clip all the layers based on all features in this fishnet grid.

I can use the iterate over layer function in the clip tool, but cannot select multiple layers. I would like this to be automatic.

So my goal is to get multiple input layers, but keep the iterate clip layer the same.

[image: iterate]

I have tried applying the knowledge in [Iterating over map layers in QGIS python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26257), but cannot seem to understand or get it to work to iterate using the Clip tool.

Comment: Notice the 'Run as batch process' button in the Clip window - have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I have, then the 'iterate over' button is gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Graphical Modeller (Processing menu) to build the desired process. Add as many layers as you like, add your grid, then switch tabs and add a clip-process for each vector-layer and set the output as final. Though it is a bit more work than simply running a batch process, it saves time if you want to/have to repeat the process.

For illustration purposes:
[image]
Purple are layers, white are processes, teal is a final output. One layer may be used for several processes, saving you some time compared to running a batch.

Comment: I cannot seem to find the irate over all features in the graphical modeller though. Importing the clip tool in the modeller also removes the iterate over option.

Comment: @B.Quaink: I changed the picture to a model that should be similar to what you would want. As said, this does require some initial work, since you have to build the iterations manually. Hope the picture now shows this better.

Comment: Thanks, this works so far. Would be nice to get a more flexible input or take a folder as input but so far this does what I asked for.