# Getting vector layer from layers within group using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgsvectorlayer, qgslayertree

It's not difficult to get a list of layers within a group in the Layers panel of a QGIS 3.x project:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
groupName = "GROUP_name"
group = root.findGroup(groupName)
layers = group.findLayers() # gets all <QgsLayerTreeLayer> objects in the group
```

Once I have the layer objects, I'm trying to apply symbology from a .qml file. This is where I run into problems - I think you need a `QgsVectorLayer` object in order to apply the symbology via the load `NamedStyle()` method as below:

```
vLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("name of layer here")[0]
vLayer.loadNamedStyle(thisQMLpath)
vLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

The gap I'm trying to fill is how to get from a list of `<QgsLayerTreeLayer>` objects to individual
`QgsVectorLayer` objects. Tried something like this using the `.mapLayersByName()` method:

```
layers = group.findLayers() # a list of <QgsLayerTreeLayer> objects in the group
for x in layers:
     vLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(x)[0]
```

but `x` is not a layer name string, so it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: The objects found by `findLayers()` are `QgsLayerTreeLayer`, which have a `layer()` method to get the corresponding `QgsVectorLayer`. That's it.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, specifically the 'Layers in TOC' section: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26257/iterating-over-map-layers-using-python-in-qgis/416933#416933 Let us know if that solves your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QgsLayerTreeLayer` has a [layer()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeLayer.html#ac7c463e2587b85cb6ca6f1de4b25d18a) method which returns `QgsMapLayer` associated with the node as @GermánCarrillo mentioned.

Use this script:

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup("GROUP_NAME")

for layer in group.findLayers():
    name = layer.layer().name() # <-
    vLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]
    vLayer.loadNamedStyle("path/to/QML")
    vLayer.triggerRepaint()
```